# join table with empty results

Tags: mysql, join, coalesce

i have two tables: `users` and `tasks`

table `users`:

```
+----------+---------------------+
|    id    |      usrname        |
+----------+---------------------+
|    1     | user1               |
+----------+---------------------+
|    2     | user2               |
+----------+---------------------+
|    3     | user3               |
+----------+---------------------+
|    4     | user4               |
+----------+---------------------+
```

table `tasks`

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    id    |      users        |      task         |   calenderweek    |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    1     | user1             | task1             | 48                |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    2     | user1             | task2             | 49                |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    3     | user2             | task1             | 50                |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    4     | user1             | task3             | 50                |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

now i want to display all users with their tasks for given calenderweek even if there is no entry for given calenderweek.

outout should look like this:

output for calenderweek(50):

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    id    |      users        |      task         |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    1     | user1             | task3             |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    2     | user2             | task1             |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    3     | user3             | no task           |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    4     | user4             | no task           |
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

i guess i need a combination of Left join and COALESCE but i never worked with them and my results are empty or my syntax is wrong.

i tried so many things that I can not think clearly anymore haha
my query looks like this at the moment:

```
SELECT  *, COALESCE(tasks.task, 'no tasks') FROM users LEFT JOIN tasks ON users.usrname = tasks.users WHERE tasks.calenderweek = '50'
```

So what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You're using `no tasks` in `COALESCE(tasks.task, 'no tasks')` but your data shows as `no task`, as posted anyway.

Comment: The best way is to handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: Next time please show code you wrote that did some part(s) correctly & code using it that didn't work. [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're almost there. [This](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sp4xh37dspCR65ScXmU4E2/0) should do the trick:

```
SELECT  *, COALESCE(tasks.task, 'no tasks') FROM users LEFT JOIN tasks ON users.usrname = tasks.users AND tasks.calenderweek = '50'
```

The problem is that you filter on `calenderweek` in the `WHERE` clause. Therefore any users without a task are left out of the result. If you place the condition in the `JOIN`, you do select all users and all users without a task get `no tasks`.

Comment: Thank you very much! you helped me a lot, now i understand it :) dont know who downvoted you but you are my hero for today! thanks!!